# Show that $h(X_n,Y_n) \to h(X$,$Y)$ almost surely

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n \to X$  and $Y_n \to Y$  , almost surely. Let $h(X,Y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function,

Show that  $h(X_n,Y_n) \to h(X$,$Y)$  almost surely

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

That $X_n\to X$ almost surely means that there exists a null-set $N_1$ such that $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in N_1^c$. Similarly, we have a null-set $N_2$ such that $Y_n(\omega)\to Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in N_2^c$. Here $^c$ denotes the complement of a set.

Now, define $N=N_1\cup N_2$. Show that $N$ is a null-set and that for $\omega\in N^c$ you have
$$
h(X_n(\omega),Y_n(\omega))\to h(X(\omega),Y(\omega))
$$
using the continuity of $h$.